# How to install avconv on Ubuntu 18.04.5 Bionic

Tags: ffmpeg, ubuntu-18.04, avconv

I want to use `avconv` for audio related operations on my `Ubuntu Bionic 18.04.5` system, but it's not getting installed as a part of the following packages.

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg:i386
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

I still get..

```
avconv: command not found
```

Comment: Why do you want avconv? Why not just use ffmpeg?

Comment: My entire project in built using avconv, I would have to port everything to ffmpeg usage. That's why I am looking for help on how to install it.

Comment: As for the ffmpeg package on 18.04, it provides ffmpeg, not avconv. avconv is not from FFmpeg. avconv is from a fork called Libav. Libav is dead. Seems like more trouble to support a dead project than to port to ffmpeg.

Answer (score 1):

So I tried creating a soft link.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/ffmpeg /usr/bin/avconv
```

Now If I run

```
$avconv

ffmpeg version 3.4.8-0ubuntu0.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers......
```